# Eclipse Autoformat Parenthesis

Tags: java, eclipse, parentheses, autoformat

I have a problem whenever I use the Scanner class in my java code:
Say I type

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)
```

As soon as I press the semicolon, it becomes/autoformats to this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in;
```

This is the only case where this issue occurs, I have never seen it happen anywhere else when coding. I also haven't found anything in the autoformat preferences that sounds like a solution to this.

I would like to know how to fix this.

Comment: You may have luck by deleting the `~/.eclipse` directory in your home folder as well as `.metadata` and `.project` in your workspace and project folder.

Comment: @MonkeySupersonic Did you try? I can reproduce in a completely fresh workspace...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this behaviour both in Eclipse Mars and Eclipse Neon, and for me it looks like a bug.

In particular, when I press <kbd>)</kbd> to over-type the auto-inserted `)`, the content assist window suggesting `System.in` stays open, and <kbd>;</kbd> then selects it and eats the `)`.

Therefore I opened a bug report for it:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=506729

To work around it (until it is fixed), you can disable one of the involved features: auto-inserting closing parenthesis, content assist (i. e. auto completion) or that content assist triggers on typing a semicolon. (All of these are available in the global preferences unter `Java -> Editor`). Alternatively you can live with the bug and close content assist either by accepting `System.in` with <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> any time after the suggestion window opens but before typing the semicolon.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense!